# Google/Facebook Sign in buttons layouts compatibility

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm integrating Google/Facebook logins in my Android app. By following the standard respective guidelines I defined the two buttons in this way:

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in_google"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in_facebook"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
```

However the two layouts differ considerably (by padding, icon sizes, back shadows, text style, etc) and the visual result is not very good:

[image]

Of course I could try and change them manually, by trying to also comply with the respective guidelines. However I guess this must be a very common issue, so I was wondering: is there any standard way or reference implementation to make the layouts more similar?

Comment: You can create custom buttons, any reason to stick with official buttons ?

Comment: Well yes but I had a look at the google rules for the buttons and you have to stick to some rules like icon sizes, proportions, etc. I don't know for fb. I'll end up doing that anyway.

Comment: splinter123 did you solve this ?